# Sorting a Vector of struct, descending or ascending order: C++

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, struct

I am trying to sort a vector of a struct in the following code. The struct has 3 data member. and I want to load a vector from these data members and sort / order by one of the struct data members. This however does not work.
I am using this as reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/
I will appreciate any help/pointers links to go-through. Thanks.

Sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct my_data {
    int data_id;
    string data_one;
    string data_two;
};

int main() {
    vector<my_data> my_vector;
    my_data new_data;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            new_data.data_id = i;
            new_data.data_one = "BBBB";
            new_data.data_two = "bbbb";
            my_vector.push_back(new_data);
        }
        if (i == 1) {
            new_data.data_id = i;
            new_data.data_one = "AAAA";
            new_data.data_two = "aaaa";
            my_vector.push_back(new_data);
        }
        if (i == 2) {
            new_data.data_id = i;
            new_data.data_one = "CCCC";
            new_data.data_two = "cccc";
            my_vector.push_back(new_data);
        }
    }
    // now, I want some help to sort my vector by "data_one",
    // something like this (below sorting function)!
    std::sort(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end(), data_one);
    for (int i = 0; i < my_vector.size(); i++) {
        cout << my_vector[i].data_id
             << "\t" << my_vector[i].data_one
             << "\t" << my_vector[i].data_two << endl;
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the following output from the print out line:

```
cout << my_vector[i].data_id << "\t" << my_vector[i].data_one << "\t" << my_vector[i].data_two << endl;

2      AAAA      aaaa
1      BBBB      bbbb
3      CCCC      cccc
```

Comment: There is no `std::sort` nor vectors in C

Comment: got it! but fixed in C++, now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a compare function for `sort` to work.

`bool myfunction (my_data i, my_data j) { return ( i.data_one < j.data_one); }`

`std::sort(my_vector.begin(),my_vector.end(),myfunction);`

Comment: thanks it works perfect, but: the  the condition should be :                  [ i.data_one < j.data_one]

Comment: well done,simple but helpful.